# NTFSprogs uninstalled ntfs-3g package

Tags: 11.10, ntfs

After installing `ntfsprogs` package, the package uninstalls *ntfs-3g* thus I can't mount my NTFS partitions through fstab

I have this line in */etc/fstab* that obviously does not work

```
UUID=6B3962A91560C093 /media/Data ntfs-3g defaults 0 0
```

Also this line does not work

```
UUID=6B3962A91560C093 /media/Data fuse.ntfs locale=es_ES.utf8 0 0
```

Any workaround?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why do you need `ntfsprogs`? I thought `ntfs-3g` contained all the `ntfsprogs` tools...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ntfsprogs` are the old ntfs tools ( mkfs.ntfs, resizentfs, etc ).  They have been superseded by the ntfs-3g package.  You can not have both versions installed at once; just stick with the ntfs-3g versions.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot!, sticking to ntfs-3g package